# Differential equations…

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

a) Show that the general solution of the differential equation $9\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+y=2-12x-x^2$ Can be expressed as $y=(A+Bx)e^{-\frac{x}{3}}-x^2+20$ for arbitrary constants $A$ and $B$.

A particular member $C$ of the family of solution curves of this equation is such that $A=-5$.

bi) Find the $y$-intercept of $C$.

bii) Deduce that $C$ crosses the positive real axis. (Don't attempt to find where this happens).

I did part a easily enough, but I keep getting part b wrong.

Edit:

For part b I've found the first and second derivatives of $y=(-5+Bx)e^{-\frac{x}{3}}-x^2+20$ And subbed them into $9\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}+6\frac{dy}{dx}+y=2-12x-x^2$ to find $B$.

Comment: Maybe you want to show you work? What are your ideas, where have you got stuck? After all, maybe it's merely a calculation error.

Comment: See my edit on the original post please.

Comment: I was trying to find the value of $B$. How would I find the $y$-intersect? (Crossing of the curve $C$ with the $y$-axis)

Comment: $B$ cannot be determined. Note that the task explicitly states that our expression i s a solution *for arbitrary constants* $A,B$.

Comment: Then how can I find the $y$-intercept?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give you some pointers:

We know our solution $C$ is of the form $C(x)=y=(-5+Bx)e^{-\frac{x}{3}}-x^2+20$.

Also, we *cannot* determine $B$ - if you look at the derivatives, you will get a solution for every possible value for $B$, so any approach in this direction will ultimately have to fail.

First of all, we want to find the $y$-intersect, or $C(0)$.

1. If we input $x=0$ into our formula for $C$, what do we get? *Does the result actually change if you put in different values for $B$?*
2. We want to show that we cross the $x$-axis at some point. If you have done the first point correctly, you should have arrived at a positive value for $C(0)$. So, if we could show that $C$ also assumes a negative value *regardless of our choice for $B$*, then, by the intermediate value theorem, we would be finished. Now, I suggest you take a look at what happens if $x$ goes to $\infty$...

Does that help?

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I was looking do a root instead of an interest for some reason.